# Rails 4.0.x how to route the root action of contact_us gem to specified action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, contactus

I'm using [contact_us](https://github.com/JDutil/contact_us) gem version 0.5.4

I've following code in my routes.rb file

```
resources :contacts, controller: 'contact_us', only: [:new, :create] do
  root :to => 'contact_us#new'
end
```

in my understanding the above route for `contacts` will only support `:new` and `:create` actions, and with specified controller `controller: 'contact_us'` also it with root `/` it will redirect to `#new` action but when I hit http://localhost:3000/contact-us in my browser it says

> Unknown action 
>   The action 'index' could not be found for ContactUsController

I've upgraded the rails version from 3.2.19 to 4.0.13 and ruby to 2.0.0p481

the old code was working fine with rails 3.2.19 and ruby 1.8.7

```
resources :contacts,
  :controller => 'contact_us',
  :only       => [:new, :create]
match 'contact_us' => 'contact_us#new'
```

if I only change `match` with `get` in above code it throws this error

> /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:430:in
>   `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'contact_us' 
>   (ArgumentError)
>
> You may have defined two routes with the same name
>   using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already
>   defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can
>   restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

adding `:as` in the route does the jobs

```
resources :contacts,
  :controller => 'contact_us',
  :only       => [:new, :create]
get 'contact_us' => 'contact_us#new', as: :contact_us2
```

as identified by [Albin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1210949/albin) in the chat the contact_us modules [route file](https://github.com/JDutil/contact_us/blob/master/config/routes.rb) it already has same route but with different alias

```
get "contact-us" => "contact_us/contacts#new", as: :contact_us #line#11
```

I just added same route with different path and different alias,

Answer (score 3):

You could do it the same way as you did in rails 3.2 you only need to exchange the `match` to a `get`. It is no longer allowed to match any verb.

```
resources :contacts,
  :controller => 'contact_us',
  :only       => [:new, :create]
get 'contact_us' => 'contact_us#new'
```

***Edit***

We solved this in a chat. It turns out that it was a collision with the gem [contanct_us](https://github.com/JDutil/contact_us).

Comment: yes I did that but it throws another error, please check question update

Comment: That is so wierd. I started a small test project new. It worked without a hitch...

Comment: Is that your entire routes file?

Comment: here is the complete route.rb file please check https://gist.github.com/riksof-zzlalani/85067363eac0b55d842926c502eb33bc

Comment: Still working. I copied your entire route file in to mine (minus the devise stuff) and it works like a charm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128360/discussion-between-albin-and-riksof-zeeshan).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
resources :contacts, controllers: 'contact_us', :only => [:new, :create]

root :to => 'contact_us#new'
# or without root 
match 'contact_us' => 'contact_us#new', via: [:get]
```

Comment: yes I did `match 'contact_us' => 'contact_us#new', via: [:get]` and it throws this error Invalid route name, already in use: 'contact_us'

Comment: still same result `Invalid route name, already in use: 'contact_us'  (ArgumentError)`

Comment: this is my code `resources :contacts, controllers: 'contact_us', :only => [:new, :create]`
 `match 'contact_us' => 'contact_us#new', via: [:get]`

Comment: try to change order meanns